# Поиск минимального свободного числа в двойном диапазоне

Tags: lua, алгоритм, выборка

Здравствуйте. У меня есть вопрос: как получить свободное число в двойном диапазоне чисел?

Предположим, вот множество: 7, 8, 10, 12, 13 - свободное число 9 (диапазон может быть разным, может состоять из 1 числа, либо его вообще может и не быть, тогда должно браться число 9 по умолчанию).
Мой второй диапазон (условие): от 9 до 12 - в него входит число 9, значит все правильно.

Примерный код, но он нерабочий:

```
local iStart = 9; -- Начало
local iEnd = 12; -- Конец диапазона
local iFree = iStart;

local a = { 7, 8, 10, 12, 13 }; -- Множество

for i, v in ipairs( a ) do
    if ( v >= iStart and v <= iEnd ) and ( i > 1 ) and ( a[ i ] - a[ i - 1 ] > 1 )  then
        iFree = v + 1;
        break;
    end
end

print( "Число: ", iFree );
```

Comment: @Kenix157, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы делал так:

1. Составил бы массив значений, начиная от min(a) до max(a) b = {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}
2. Далее циклом идем по массиву а и смотрим: если текущее значение попадает в промежуток от 9 до 12 и его НЕТ в массиве а, то это наше число.

P.S. Вот метод для проверки, есть ли значение в массиве:

https://gist.github.com/crazyR14/8acb6c95f78b416714ee